# MVC Routing - combine parameters into action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to take a path such as:

/reports/{controller}/{reportType}/{report}

And turn it into:

/reports/{controller}/{reportType-report}

Where reportType-report is an Action Method? The reason we'd like to do this is for authentication. We need to limit each report to certain users, which we can do on a per action method basis.

Comment: The '-' character is not allowed in method names so you would not be able to target an action with a name of this format.  Also relying on the action name for authorization doesn't seem like a good idea.  Use the `AuthorizeAttribute` as @Mike Cheel suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to restrict on per action basis, why not leverage the AuthorizeAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to say.

Comment: Right, we are using the AuthorizeAttribute. My question relates to how to route the requests.

How can I request /reports/reportController/type1/aReport and end up calling a specific action method related to that report so that we can use the AuthorizeAttribute? I am new to MVC, so I'm not sure if I am asking this correctly or not.

Comment: The 'aReport' would fill in the id portion of the default route if you wanted to be that way. I'm not 100% clear what you are asking though to be honest. Does your route look like: "reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}"?

Comment: We want to get away from the aReport being an id, as it wouldn't be possible to restrict access based on the report (using the authorize attribute), right? Assuming it can't be done like that, is there a way to have the URL be in that format but have a specific action method for each report? So when you request /reports/reportController/type1/aReport it's tied to a specific method rather than taking aReport as an id in the type1 method. Apologies for making this difficult.

Comment: Is the type1 necessary? Right now that is the action. I don't understand the context of type1 so don't know. You could get away with reports/{controller}/type1/{Action}/{id} and make id optional (in other words omit it). You would have to create a route for each typex though if typex is important.

Comment: Ahh, I think that could work. I think I will give that a shot. The type is more for clarity than anything else. Thanks!